# MySQL, MariaDB: Cannot create a table - ERROR 1005 (HY000). Something wrong with foreign key

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am new to databases and I keep getting an error when I try to create these tables. Where is a mistake?

I have found loads of questions similar to mine, but they didn't help me to resolve this problem.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS course
(
    cou_id VARCHAR(3),
    course_name VARCHAR(25),
    CONSTRAINT pk_course PRIMARY KEY (cou_id, course_name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students_marks
(
    stu_id INT, 
    student_name VARCHAR(25), 
    course_name VARCHAR(25), 
    first_mark NUMERIC(2,0), 
    second_mark NUMERIC(2,0), 
    third_mark NUMERIC(2,0),
    CONSTRAINT pk_studentsmarks PRIMARY KEY (stu_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_studentsmarks_course FOREIGN KEY (course_name) REFERENCES course (course_name)
);
```

This is from INNODB STATUS.

```
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
130603 20:17:22 Error in foreign key constraint of table testdb/students_marks:
 FOREIGN KEY (course_name) REFERENCES course (course_name)
):
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
for correct foreign key definition.
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary key is set to `cou_id` and `course_name` in your course table.  To add a foreign key constraint in your students_marks table, you'd have to reference both fields (and include both fields in your table definition):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS course
(
    cou_id VARCHAR(3),
    course_name VARCHAR(25),
    CONSTRAINT pk_course PRIMARY KEY (cou_id, course_name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students_marks
(
    stu_id INT, 
    student_name VARCHAR(25), 
    cou_id VARCHAR(3),
    course_name VARCHAR(25), 
    first_mark NUMERIC(2,0), 
    second_mark NUMERIC(2,0), 
    third_mark NUMERIC(2,0),
    CONSTRAINT pk_studentsmarks PRIMARY KEY (stu_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_studentsmarks_course FOREIGN KEY (cou_id,course_name) REFERENCES course(cou_id,course_name)
);
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc992)

Comment: I keep getting an error, even when I copy and paste working example from SQL Fiddle. But code works in SQL Fiddle. Any ideas?

Comment: @doc -- did you include the cou_id in the table definition for student_marks?  It's working locally for me, as well as on the fiddle.

Comment: Yes, I have copied your example from sx to my sql script. And also it works in sql fiddle but not on my system...Weird. However if I remove the last line with foreign key, everything works.

Comment: Make sure reference and foreign key column types are exactly of same type. Even if it was int(21) and int(15) difference it may fail.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing only one field of a composed primary key!